# C# return statement determined dynamically

Tags: c#

Could someone give me an advice on this issue, so what am I doing is receiving username and password as parameters. 
If that is ok (checking credentials) I want to return QR code of it, and if not i want to return string (or boolean or void).

Is their a solution for this? So is it possible not to know return statement?

Comment: i found an example that returns Bitmap, but that is not that relevant, just want to know a way to dynamically determine return

Comment: You can create Getter/Setter Class and return the object of that class.

Comment: You could return a null QR code object to indicate failure. Or you could throw an exception

Comment: great! how didn't i literally thought of that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class whose object will be returned. In that class you can add properties.

```
class ReturnClass
{
    public string QRCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsOK { get; set; }
}

public ReturnClass MainMethod()
{
    ReturnClass mrc = new ReturnClass();

    // Do checks and populate value of ReturnClass

    return mrc;
}
```

Comment: ok great, thank you! will accept the answer in few minutes :)

Comment: This prevents the need to find out what type you are sending back on the client side, but is there a lot of need for it to always return a bool too?

Comment: You can skip bool property and directly use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(QRCode)`

Comment: Yep that's very true. Then you don't actually even need the class ReturnClass, you can just return string, and return an empty string or null if credential check fails.

Comment: @jwddixon: You are correct but in future if requirement changes, then all you have to do is add a property in `ReturnClass` and use that property.

Answer (score 0):

Just return an object. Then you can return whatever object you like and check on the requester's side what type was returned.

```
public object returnObject(string user, string pwd)
{
    if(checkCredentials(user,pwd))
    return new QRcode(usr,pwd);

    else 
    return false;
}
```